# Code throws null reference error, even though I null-checked everything

Tags: c#, .net

I have some code that throws a null reference error:

```
72    if (query.allergy != null && query.allergy.Count > 0)
73    {
74        for (var i = 0; i < (query?.allergy?.Count ?? 0); i++) // <-- this line throws null reference exception
```

It seems I have null-checked everything here. How can it possibly throw a null reference error?

I don't have a chance to debug this remotely, so I don't know which part of the code is null.

Stack trace:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.   at XXXXXXXXX.Helpers.ProductHelper.processEntities(List`1 entities, String language) in C:\Users\XXXXXX\Dropbox\code\bots\XXXX\Helpers\ProductHelper.cs:line 74

I'm sure about the line number, I shifted the code by a few lines to make sure that this is this line, and the line number changed.

Comment: What if query is null? (I'm talking about if (query.allergy != null....))

Comment: Are you sure the exception is thrown in the `for` line and not in the `if` one?

Comment: Are you sure it's that line and not the one above: `if (query.allergy...` could throw if `query` is null.

Comment: Please add the stacktrace. You have nearly 4k rep. You should know [ask]. ;)

Comment: @Pikoh Absolutely sure by looking at stack trace

Comment: @Fildor added stacktrace

Comment: Please show a [mcve]. We can't really help with just this snippet.

Comment: Either your debugging symbols are wrong/off (something even optimization can do), causing the stack trace to misreport the actual line, or you've got an even less probable error in the JIT compiler.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Bingo! You were right. The offending code was a few lines lower. How the hell can the debugging symbols be off by a few lines?

Comment: Excellent question. Make it a separate one, maybe the MS developers will finally weigh in. :-) In short, though, while the debugging symbols reference the IL, I think occasionally the ball is dropped when the JIT compiler optimizes the code and doesn't get the references quite right as it shuffles around code. I think the C# compiler itself is blameless. But this is pure speculation on my part, even though I've seen it happen lots of times. When you get a curious stack trace, always try to repro on a debug build first, it's more reliable.

Comment: @K48 When you are sure that `query != null`, then you can remove all  null propagation operator within the `for` loop.